# sympy binary variable definition

Tags: sympy

I want to define a symbol in sympy so that I get the following simplification when I have squares of binary variables:

```
>>> b = symbols('b', binary=True)
>>> b**2
b
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can create a Symbol subclass and define `_eval_power`.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, you can define your own symbol class by subclassing `Symbol`, for example:

```py
class Binary(Symbol):
    def _eval_power(self, other):
        return self
```

This will cause any power of a `Binary` symbol to return the symbol itself (note: not just squaring, as in the question).

For example, let's define a binary variable and take some power of it:

```py
b = Binary("b")
print(b**2)
```

which returns just `b`, as expected. Contrast that with using a regular `Symbol`:

```py
s = Symbol("s")
print(s**2)
```

which returns `s**2`, as expected.

You can also use the new `Binary` class elsewhere in place of `Symbol`, for example to define a list of binary variables, like so:

```py
bs = symbols([f"b{i}" for i in range(10)], cls=Binary)
```